# Integrate a basic auth protected API with AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a legacy API which is Basic Auth protected. I created in AWS Gateway a HTTP API and added the legacy API endpoint integration. Now when I try to add the "Authorization" header to provide the basic auth credentials I get an error saying "Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Operations on header authorization are restricted]".

How do I provide the basic auth infos in AWS API Gateway?

Comment: I've figured out that this restriction exists in the "HTTP API" api gateway type and not "REST API" api gateway type. I've resolved it by making a new api with "REST API" type